# Unable to access application using URL

Tags: apache, web-services, ssl-certificate, httpd.conf, atlassian-fisheye

I am unable to access one of the web application using URL,but it is possible to access using the hostname:port.

I am using the Server: Apache/2.2.15 (Unix).

The httpd logs shows below error.

```
[Sun Jan 10 07:36:46 2016] [notice] child pid 12490 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Sun Jan 10 07:36:46 2016] [notice] child pid 12491 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Sun Jan 10 07:36:46 2016] [error] NSS_Initialize failed. Certificate database: /etc/httpd/alias.
[Sun Jan 10 07:36:46 2016] [error] SSL Library Error: -8038 SEC_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED
[Sun Jan 10 07:36:46 2016] [error] NSS_Initialize failed. Certificate database: /etc/httpd/alias.
[Sun Jan 10 07:36:46 2016] [error] SSL Library Error: -8038 SEC_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED
[Sun Jan 10 07:36:46 2016] [error] NSS_Initialize failed. Certificate database: /etc/httpd/alias.
[Sun Jan 10 07:36:46 2016] [error] SSL Library Error: -8038 SEC_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED
[Sun Jan 10 07:36:46 2016] [error] NSS_Initialize failed. Certificate database: /etc/httpd/alias.
[Sun Jan 10 07:36:46 2016] [error] SSL Library Error: -8038 SEC_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED
[Sun Jan 10 07:36:47 2016] [notice] child pid 12492 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Sun Jan 10 07:36:47 2016] [notice] child pid 12493 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Sun Jan 10 07:36:47 2016] [notice] child pid 12494 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Sun Jan 10 07:36:47 2016] [notice] child pid 12495 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Sun Jan 10 07:36:47 2016] [error] NSS_Initialize failed. Certificate database: /etc/httpd/alias.
[Sun Jan 10 07:36:47 2016] [error] SSL Library Error: -8038 SEC_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED
[Sun Jan 10 07:36:47 2016] [error] NSS_Initialize failed. Certificate database: /etc/httpd/alias.
[Sun Jan 10 07:36:47 2016] [error] SSL Library Error: -8038 SEC_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED
[Sun Jan 10 07:36:47 2016] [error] NSS_Initialize failed. Certificate database: /etc/httpd/alias.
[Sun Jan 10 07:36:47 2016] [error] SSL Library Error: -8038 SEC_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED
[Sun Jan 10 07:36:47 2016] [error] NSS_Initialize failed. Certificate database: /etc/httpd/alias.
[Sun Jan 10 07:36:47 2016] [error] SSL Library Error: -8038 SEC_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED
[Sun Jan 10 07:36:47 2016] [error] NSS_Initialize failed. Certificate database: /etc/httpd/alias.
[Sun Jan 10 07:36:47 2016] [error] SSL Library Error: -8038 SEC_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED
[Sun Jan 10 07:36:47 2016] [error] NSS_Initialize failed. Certificate database: /etc/httpd/alias.
[Sun Jan 10 07:36:47 2016] [error] SSL Library Error: -8038 SEC_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED
[Sun Jan 10 07:36:47 2016] [error] NSS_Initialize failed. Certificate database: /etc/httpd/alias.
[Sun Jan 10 07:36:47 2016] [error] SSL Library Error: -8038 SEC_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED
[Sun Jan 10 07:36:47 2016] [error] NSS_Initialize failed. Certificate database: /etc/httpd/alias.
[Sun Jan 10 07:36:47 2016] [error] SSL Library Error: -8038 SEC_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED
[Sun Jan 10 07:36:48 2016] [notice] child pid 12496 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Sun Jan 10 07:36:48 2016] [notice] child pid 12497 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
```

Comment: Possible solution found with a search engine: http://www.sononaco.com/blog/apache-refuses-to-start-after-yum-update-on-centos-5/